# Lines from text view disappear in screen shot in android app

Tags: android

In an android app, I have a screen with a few buttons, a `TextView` and an `ImageView`. In the screenshot (a ".jpg" file) of this screen taken during the execution, only the first and some times second text line from the `TextView` is captured. Interestingly, the last screen shot contains all the lines from the `TextView`.

Can anyone suggest the cause and suitable remedy ?

Screen has 3 buttons at the top (which are made invisible before taking the screen shot), then a TextView and an ImageView is at the bottom.

---------------------The layout file (solveallline1.xml)------------------------

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SolveLine1" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >
            <TableRow>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b_prev"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Previous Step" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b_next"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Next Step" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b_exit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Exit" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DrawingTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/DrawingImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

There are 13 steps in the code. After the end of each step a screen shot is taken. The height of the ImageView in each screenshot is varying depending on the number of lines of text in TextView of the previous screen shot. So the lines in TextView of every screen shot are getting truncated if they are more in number as compared to the previous screen shot. (For example,Screen shot for step11 shows only 2 text lines, as step10 has 2 text lines in the TextView)

-----------The code for calling screenshot function in steps10 & 11 :-----------

```
void drawStep10(){
        p1=getPaint(p1,"white",getStokeWidth(pxl),getTextSize(pxl),false);
        canvas.drawText("Step9", brx / 4, bry - pxl*2/100, p1);
        p1=getPaint(p1,"black",getStokeWidth(pxl),getTextSize(pxl),false);
        canvas.drawText("a'",aa_dash.x+pxl*3/100,aa_dash.y+pxl*5/100,p1);
        canvas.drawText("b1'",b1_dash.x-pxl*7/100,b1_dash.y+pxl*5/100,p1);
        aaa_dash.drawLn(canvas,p1,a,aa_dash);
        b1b1_dash.drawLn(canvas,p1,b1,b1_dash);
        p1=getPaint(p1,"blue",getStokeWidth(pxl),getTextSize(pxl),false);
        canvas.drawText("Step10", brx / 4, bry - pxl*2/100, p1);
        len4=b1_dash.x-aa_dash.x;
        alfa = (float)Math.asin((d.y-q.y)/(float)len4);
        dalfa = (float)Math.toDegrees(alfa);//alfa in degrees
        len5 = len4*Math.cos(alfa);
        ilen5 = Integer.valueOf(len5.intValue());
        b2_dash = new Point(aa_dash.x+ilen5,q.y);
        RectF oval = new RectF();
        oval.set(aa_dash.x-len4,aa_dash.y-len4,aa_dash.x+len4,aa_dash.y+len4);
        canvas.drawArc(oval,0,dalfa*(-1),false,p1);
        canvas.drawText("b2'",b2_dash.x+pxl*3/100,b2_dash.y+pxl*5/100,p1);
        p1=getPaint(p1,"red",getStokeWidth(pxl),getTextSize(pxl),false);
        canvas.drawLine(aa_dash.x,aa_dash.y,b2_dash.x,b2_dash.y,p1);
        canvas.drawText("<-- center", aa_dash.x+pxl*1/100, aa_dash.y+pxl*1/100, p1);
        canvas.drawText("<-- radius", ((aa_dash.x+b2_dash.x)/2)+pxl*2/100,(aa_dash.y+b2_dash.y)/2, p1);
        drawingTextView.setText("Draw an Arc b1'b2' with Point a' as center. The Arc b1'b2'" +
                " intersects Line pq at Point b2'");
        drawingImageView.invalidate();
        takeScreenshot("Step10");
    }
void drawStep11(){
        p1=getPaint(p1,"white",getStokeWidth(pxl),getTextSize(pxl),false);
        canvas.drawText("Step10", brx / 4, bry - pxl*2/100, p1);
        canvas.drawLine(aa_dash.x,aa_dash.y,b2_dash.x,b2_dash.y,p1);
        canvas.drawText("<-- center", aa_dash.x+pxl*1/100, aa_dash.y+pxl*1/100, p1);
        canvas.drawText("<-- radius", ((aa_dash.x+b2_dash.x)/2)+pxl*2/100,(aa_dash.y+b2_dash.y)/2, p1);
        p1=getPaint(p1,"black",getStokeWidth(pxl),getTextSize(pxl),false);
        RectF oval = new RectF();
        oval.set(aa_dash.x-len4,aa_dash.y-len4,aa_dash.x+len4,aa_dash.y+len4);
        canvas.drawArc(oval,0,dalfa*(-1),false,p1);
        canvas.drawText("b2'",b2_dash.x+pxl*3/100,b2_dash.y+pxl*5/100,p1);
        p1=getPaint(p1,"blue",getStokeWidth(pxl),getTextSize(pxl),false);
        canvas.drawText("Step11", brx / 4, bry - pxl*2/100, p1);
        aa_dashb2_dash = new Line();
        aa_dashb2_dash.drawLn(canvas,p1,aa_dash,b2_dash);
        p1=getPaint(p1,"green",getStokeWidth(pxl),getTextSize(pxl),false);
        canvas.drawText("<-- ϴ =" + theta, adx+pxl*4/100, ady , p1);
        canvas.drawText("<-- Φ =" + phi, a.x+pxl*4/100, a.y+pxl*3/100 , p1);
        canvas.drawText("<-- α =" + Math.floor(dalfa * 100) / 100, aa_dash.x+pxl*4/100, aa_dash.y , p1);
        drawingTextView.setText("Draw a Line a'b2'. Measure Angle b1'a'b2'(α)= " +
                Math.floor(dalfa * 100) / 100+"\n"+
                "Note4:Line a'b2' is the projection of line and is the Front View of the line" +
                " making an angle Φ = "+ phi+" with VP and ϴ = "+theta+" with HP. Angle α = " +
                Math.floor(dalfa * 100) / 100+
                " is made by the projection of the line with HP");
        drawingImageView.invalidate();
        takeScreenshot("Step11");
    }
```

-----------------The screenshot function :----------------------------

```
private void takeScreenshot(String s1) {
        try {
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + s1 + ".jpg";
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            imageFile = new File(mPath);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            b1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

---

Comment: Please post your code where you make screenshot with method in which it placed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: there likely is a problem in your code, the way you are taking a screenshot.

Comment: I am new to this forum, so please forgive me if I fail to follow the norms of the forum. Where do I post the code ? It will not fit in the space available for comment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I added some formatting to improve the readability of your question. And I removed the "thank you" because many users like to keep posts focused on the programming problem so they will be helpful to future readers as well. This may seem strange, but I think they had to draw a line somewhere. And it's easier to completely ban things like "thank you" than to decide which form of gratitude is too verbose and which is basically ok.

Comment: You can edit your question by clicking on "edit" (below the `android` tag). Please feel free to ask if anything else is unclear.

Comment: Where do I post the code ? It does not fit in the space available for comment.

Comment: You should put the code into the question (you can always edit your own question) To start editing your question, click on "edit" - it's written in small letters just below the `android` tag

Comment: I have added code as suggested. I will appreciate if somebody could inform why the TextView is getting truncated in the screenshots.